# OpenFileOutput() gets an nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, bluetooth, android-handler

I have created a static Handler to receive data from a thread that listens for incoming Bluetooth data.
This handler calls: measure_finish2() and this method calls a non-static metod called: measure_finish(), inside the last one i need to call the openFileOutput method but i have a nullPointerException, even when i call a simple Toast i have the same nullPointrException, this is part of my code:

```
    public class MainActivity Extends Activity{
    ...
    public void sending_tubes_to_clean(){
        stream_cleaning_tubes = "15";
        for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
            if(itemsChecked[i] == true){
                stream_cleaning_tubes += "," + Integer.toString(i+1);
            }
        }
        if(conectToServerThread != null){
            conectToServerThread.commsThread.write(stream_cleaning_tubes);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cleaning the selected Tubes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cleaning_status();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You must be connected to the Viscometer!...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.d(tag,stream_cleaning_tubes);
    }        
public static Handler MainReceiver = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                int numOfBytesReceived = msg.arg1;
                byte[] buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strReceived = new String(buffer);
                String comand;
                strReceived = strReceived.substring(3,numOfBytesReceived);
                comand = strReceived.substring(0,2);

                if(comand.toString().equals("03")){
                    //MainActivity o = new MainActivity();
                    measure_finish2(strReceived.substring(3));
                    //measure_finish2(strReceived.substring(3));
                }

            }
        };
        public static String get_data(String aux){
            String aux2 = null;
            aux2 = aux.substring(0,aux.indexOf(","));
            return aux2;
        }

        public static void measure_finish2(String data){
            MainActivity o = new MainActivity();
            o.measure_finish(data);
        }
        public void measure_finish(String data){
            String data_to_save,strdate,tube,temp,time,cte_tube,visco;
            String file_name = "results.txt";
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
            strdate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            tube = get_data(data);
            data = data.substring(data.indexOf(",")+1);
            temp = get_data(data);
            data = data.substring(data.indexOf(",")+1);
            time = get_data(data);
            data = data.substring(data.indexOf(",")+1);
            cte_tube = get_data(data);
            data = data.substring(data.indexOf(",")+1);
            visco = get_data(data);
            data_to_save = sample_id_var + user_id_var + strdate + "Tube# " + tube + temp + "°C"+ cte_tube + time + "s" + visco + "cSt" + "\n";
            try{
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(file_name,MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                try {
                    osw.write(data_to_save);
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "F saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            samp_id_view.setText(data_to_save);
            cleaning_status();
        }
```

please anyone can help me, this is the error that i have:

```
 04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685): Process: com.callirgos.viscopi, PID: 1685
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     ... 10 more
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:181)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.callirgos.viscopi.MainActivity.measure_finish(MainActivity.java:434)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.callirgos.viscopi.MainActivity.measure_finish2(MainActivity.java:415)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     at com.callirgos.viscopi.MainActivity.test_files(MainActivity.java:478)
04-17 17:09:18.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1685):     ... 13 more
```

Comment: As you can see in the logcat your NullPointerException is caused by MainActivity.sending_tubes_to_clean(MainActivity.java:320). But you did not post the code where you displayed a Toast.

Comment: Yep, but inside that method there is just a Toast:

Comment: I have update my post, look them, please if anyone now how to solve this tell me...

Comment: You still have the forbidden 'new MainActivity'. And we cannot see the function with that Toast called. Please adapt your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MainActivity o = new MainActivity();
```

First, **NEVER** create an instance of an `Activity` yourself. Android's framework creates those, not you. This `o` is not properly initialized, and so any attempts to use it, for `openFileOutput()`, a `Toast`, etc., will generally crash.

Second, do not do disk I/O on the main application thread. The code shown in `measure_finish()` should be done either by the Bluetooth thread or by another background thread, not the main application thread.

Comment: This is of course the cause of the error.  But likely the real mistake is in making this class extend Activity - it does not really seem to have much to do with anything that Activities do.  What probably should be done is to pass a valid Context or other reference to an Activity into it, which can then be used to do things like show a toast or obtain package paths.  Then creating an instance with `new` will be legitimate.

Comment: Add a Context argument to the constructor where you pass "this" from the triggering Activity.  It would be even better to simply pas the directory obtained from getFilesDir() but then you'd have to jump through an extra step of creating a file with that as the parent and your specified file name as the second argument, calling its setReadable(true, false) to set the world readable permission, and then creating a FileOutputStream from it.

Comment: CommonsWare was right, i moved my I/O task to a Background Thread an passed context as parameter, now my code works fine.